# Unexplained redirect using VirtualHosts and ServerAlias

Tags: apache, redirect, ubuntu

Using a virtual host, and a server alias, I'm getting a strange redirect that I do not understand where it is coming from.

Using stock apache2 on Ubuntu 12.04. Only the following changes to files in `/etc/apache2/...`

I have added a new virtual host as follows in the file `sites-available/foo-com` and enabled it with `a2ensite`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.foo.om
    ServerAlias foo.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www/www.foo.com 
    <Directory /var/www/www.foo.com/>
            Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I also have a second virtual host for `www.bar.com`, which is exactly the same as above, but with `foo` replaced by `bar`

I have changed the default virtual host to a different document root

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www/default 
    <Directory /var/www/default/>
    .....
```

When I navigate to `http://foo.com`, I get a 301 redirect to `http://www.foo.com/www.foo.com` , which obviously returns a `404`. Even more strangely, navigating to `http://bar.com` returns the relevant site correctly without a redirect.

I've been tearing my hair out trying to understand this strange behaviour. I've verified that there are no redirect's anywhere else in the apache confs. There is no reference to `foo.com` anywhere except the virtual host above. There is no .htaccess files in the document root.. I created the directory from scratch.

What else could be causing this?

Comment: A few suggestions: (1) Set `LogLevel debug`, and check the error log. (2) `egrep -ri '(Redirect|RewriteRule)' /etc/apache2` to be sure there aren't more redirects you haven't found. (3) Turn up `RewriteLogLevel` to 3 or higher and check the rewrite log.

Comment: Thanks. I'd already grep'd the directory for any instances for rewrite, there is nothing other than the DAV related ones set to `redirect-carefully` from the default install, none of them actually redirect to a url.

Comment: Thanks for the other suggestions. Nothing comes up in the error log. Enabling the rewrite log shows that the rewrite is happening, but I can't see why it should. The Gist is here, would you care to take a look? https://gist.github.com/aviks/8384895

Comment: An .htaccess in /var/www ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/howto/htaccess.html

> Further note that httpd must look for .htaccess files in all
>   higher-level directories, in order to have a full complement of
>   directives that it must apply. (See section on how directives are
>   applied.) Thus, if a file is requested out of a directory
>   /www/htdocs/example, httpd must look for the following files:
>
> /.htaccess
>   /www/.htaccess
>   /www/htdocs/.htaccess
>   /www/htdocs/example/.htaccess

Looking at your rewrite log, it would seem you have a .htaccess file stuck in /var/www . Removing it or, preferably, disabling .htaccess should solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, the [gist](https://gist.github.com/aviks/8384895) clearly shows that.  And since it only affects foo.com, it must be in or under /var/www/www.foo.com.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, there was a .htaccess at the higher level directory. Phew!